# Get pixel on a bitmap with c++ visual studio 2008

Tags: gdi+, gdi

i am totally beginner...i would like to use getpixel code on a bitmap with a very simple code and store it in array...msdn dosnt help much for me...

Help me...
Thanks

Comment: Changing from C++ to GDI tags

Answer (score 2):

I had updated Mitch's answer to include the following. I was going to let him have the credit by just editing this into his answer, then he delete the answer. :(

C++ version:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"Grapes.jpg", false);
Gdiplus::Color color = pBmp->GetPixel(50,50);
```

Don't forget to call GdiplusStartup when your app initializes. What's really useful about the link below is that it contains a complete working problem sample to init GDI+ and to load a file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, that link is really useful.